# How to scrape hidden website using python :: style display:none

Tags: python, python-requests, data-mining, python-requests-html

I was trying to scrape website and I faced a problem: the data in the website is hidden and, when I clicked the "+" sign it showed the result.

How do I scrape this data using python?

```
    <tr class="ob_gDGC" style="display: none;">
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything, done any research? What is the issue, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The style only denotes what the screen displays not what the document is, so display:none doesn't restrict you from accessing the data.

However if the data you are trying to access is not on the dom then you have a problem. View the page in dev tools to see if the data is there before you click the button. If you click the button and it appends children (or the dom node flashes in google chrome dev tools) then the website you are trying to scrape uses javascript dom manipulation and this is difficult to impossible to extract with the requests library. For that you would be looking for the package like [pyppeteer](https://pypi.org/project/pyppeteer/) (or equivalent). With that you could get a web page and simulate the click event on "the plus sign" and then extract your required data.

I would advise you modify your post to be a bit clearer and add a example of the dom you are trying to scrape.